# Regular expression using Question mark

Tags: python-3.x

I have some string as below(each in new line):

```
aa1 !=5
bb1 >=1
cc1 ==1
dd2 <= 2
e3 <2
```

From this string, I want to get a list of all the labels that are before the comparison operator and another list that contains the values after the comparison operator. that is:

```
list1 = ['aa1','bb1','cc1','dd2','e3']
list2 = ['5','1','1','2','2']
```

How will I be able to do that?

I have tried the code below:

```
[v.strip() for v in re.findall("[a-zA-Z0-9_.]* ? (?(!=|==|<=|>=|>|<)\=)", string)]
```

Expected result:

```
list1 = ['aa1','bb1','cc1','dd2','e3']
list2 = ['5','1','1','2','2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect regex, use this regex instead (you don't need a question mark in your regex, the question mark matches `0` or `1` instances of what's before it):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*(!=|==|<=|>=|>|<)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Test:

```
import re

s = '''aa1 !=5
bb1 >=1
cc1 ==1
dd2 <= 2
e3 <2'''

rgx = '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*(!=|==|<=|>=|>|<)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'

list1 = []
list2 = []

for m in re.findall(rgx, s):
  list1.append(m[0])
  list2.append(m[2])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd2', 'e3']
['5', '1', '1', '2', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y= "aa1 !=5 bb1 >=1 cc1 ==1 dd2 <= 2 e3 <2"
>>> x= np.array([v for v in re.split("(!=|==|<=|>=|>|<| )", y) if len(v.strip())>0]).reshape(-1, 3)
>>> x
array([['aa1', '!=', '5'],
       ['bb1', '>=', '1'],
       ['cc1', '==', '1'],
       ['dd2', '<=', '2'],
       ['e3', '<', '2']], dtype='<U3')
>>> list1 = x[:, 0]
>>> list1
array(['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd2', 'e3'], dtype='<U3')
>>> list2 = x[:, 2]
>>> list2
array(['5', '1', '1', '2', '2'], dtype='<U3')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
s = """aa1 !=5 
bb1 >=1 
cc1 ==1 
dd2 <= 2 
e3 <2"""

symbol = ['!=','==','>=','<=','>','<']
p = '|'.join(symbol)
sep = re.findall(p, s)
res = [s.split('\n')[i].split(sep[i]) for i in range(len(sep))]
print(res)
```

Output

```
[['aa1 ', '5 '], ['bb1 ', '1 '], ['cc1 ', '1 '], ['dd2 ', ' 2 '], ['e3 ', '2']]
```

---

```
list1 = [i[0].strip(' ') for i in res] #['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd2', 'e3']
list2 = [i[1].strip(' ') for i in res] #['5', '1', '1', '2', '2']
```